# Possibility of defining Chern character form in terms of odd Chern Character form?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, characteristic-classes, chern-simons-theory

Given a complex vector bundle $E\to X$ with a connection $\nabla^E$ and an automorphism $U$ of $E\to X$, one can define an odd Chern character form $\textrm{ch}(\nabla, U)$ in terms of Chern character form as follows. Denote by $\pi:X\times S^1\to X$ the projection onto the first factor. Then $$\widetilde{\nabla}=dt\wedge\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+(1-t)\nabla+tU^*\nabla$$
is a connection on $\pi^*E\to X\times S^1$. Then the odd Chern character form is defined as
$$\textrm{ch}(\nabla, U)=\int_{S^1}\textrm{ch}(\widetilde{\nabla}).$$

My question is whether we can reverse the whole process, i.e., defining the Chern character form in terms of the odd Chern character form (and probably integration along the fibers)?

One guess is, for a given complex vector bundle $E\to X$ with a connection $\nabla$, consider the vector bundle $\pi^*E\to X\times S^1$, and define an automorphism $U$ by parallel transport around the circle fibers. Then integrate the odd Chern character form $\textrm{ch}(\pi^*\nabla, U)$ (no matter which definition one uses) along the fibers of $\pi:X\times S^1\to X$...

I am not sure if this simple guess would work, and I don't find any papers talking about this or any other ways of defining the Chern character form in terms of the odd Chern character form. Well, after all I understand that this question is quite strange.